# Understanding the way ticks loops work in Netlogo

Tags: while-loop, netlogo

It is stupid but Netlogo is giving me some troubles with ticks.
From what I have understood, the following syntaxe is equivalent to a while loop on ticks value, and should print 0 then 1 and so on until 9, when it stops.

```
to go
  reset-ticks
  if ticks >= 10 [stop]
  print ticks
  tick
end
```

But for some reason it just prints 0 when executed. Could someone explain me why ? I could not find an answer.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

If you want a while loop, use [while](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#while).  There is nothing special about the `go` procedure.  If you call it once, it will run once, doing exactly as you observe.

*However*, it is conventional to add a `Go` button to the NetLogo interface and to make this a "forever button".  This means that if you press the button once it will call the attached procedure repeatedly. Doing this with your `go` procedure is described in [Tutorial 3](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/tutorial3.html).